# Python requests with stream reads only 8-9 mb of a file and stops

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to read and encode 1 mb chunks of a file using requests library. One file is of 96 mb and another is of 15 mb in size. The code exits the loop without any error after 8-9 iterations.

I have tried the following:

```
    with requests.get(url, stream=True, verify=False) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        mb_pushed = 0
        # read 1048576 bytes at a time
        for block in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1048576):
            # encode content
            encoded_content = base64.standard_b64encode(block)
            # push the encoded block
            dbfs_rpc('add-block', {'data': encoded_content, 'handle': handler})
            _logger.info('Pushed %smb' % str(mb_pushed + 1))
            mb_pushed += 1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you download the whole file manually, like from a browser, without errors?

Comment: did you try smaller `chunk_size` like `1024` ?

Comment: @abdusco Yes I am able to download the files from the browser

Comment: @furas The requirement is to encode chunks of 1mb only.

Comment: you can read in small chunks and encode when you get 1MB. Usually sockets in system use small buffer to read data from network - about 8KB - and maybe it is problem.

Comment: but first question is if you can get all data when you read with browser or wget or curl.

Comment: @furas Yes I am able to get the whole file from browser itself